# Why is $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]3 , e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}} ) \cap \mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}} ) = \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Say $\zeta_1 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}} $, $\zeta_2 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{7}} $ and $\zeta_3 = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{35}} $ . Define $E_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]3 , \zeta_1)$ and $E_2 = \mathbb{Q}( \zeta_2)$

Show $E_1 \cap E_2 = \mathbb{Q}$ by Galois theorem.

(Hints : The splitting field, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]3 , \zeta_3)$ for $f(x) = (x^5 -3)(x^7-1)$)

I'm trying to prove above considering "any $\sigma$" in $H_1 \cap H_2$, $\sigma(\sqrt[5]3) =\sqrt[5]3 $ and $\sigma(\zeta_i) =\zeta_i$. (Here $H_i= G(K /E_i)$ and $i \in \{1,2\}$)

But I've stuck to proceed the next step. Please help me. Plus another method also welcomed.

Best regards.

Comment: Another method not using Galois Theory at all, and far too advanced for your purposes: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[5]3,\zeta_1)$ is ramified only above $3$ and $5$; $\Bbb Q(\zeta_2)$ is ramified only above $7$. The intersection will ramify nowhere, i.e. it’ll be an unramified extension of $\Bbb Q$. But the rationals have no proper extension that’s unramified everywhere.

Comment: I might also consider the following. The degrees are $[E_1:\Bbb{Q}]=20$ and $[E:2:\Bbb{Q}]=6$, so the intersection is either trivial or a quadratic subfield. It turns out that that the unique quadratic subfield of $E_2$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and that of $E_1$ is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$. But these rely on a few facts that may or may not have been covered. A) a mechanism for finding the quadratic  subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/p})$, B) an understanding of the structure of the Galois group $Gal(E_1/\Bbb{Q})$.

Comment: (cont'd) Neither is too arduous, but it may depend on the tastes of the teacher whether the necessary thinking is included. Item B) relies on the observation that the squares of the elements of $Gal(E_1/\Bbb{Q})$ for a dihedral group of order ten. Anyway, it is surely a standard exercise to show that the two quadratic fields are not equal.

Comment: I have a concern about the suggested attack. Probably you need to know what kind of automorphic images the root of unity $\xi=e^{2\pi i/35}$ can have. If that has been covered in the course, you know that they have the form $\xi\mapsto \xi^k, \gcd(k,35)=1$, and there are $24$ of them. But with this fact in place we immediately see that the compositum $E_1E_2$ is a degree $120$ extension. And this already implies that $E_1\cap E_2$ must be trivial. Anyway, thinking about the various ways around such field extensions is useful for learning :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Thanks for your always kindness. Oh my.... I just now found the seious typo. I edited $H_i$

Comment: @Lubin this answer is so satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Galois group $G(K/\Bbb Q)$ has order $5\cdot\varphi (35)=120$.

Since the extensions $E_i/\Bbb Q$ are of degrees $5\cdot \varphi (5)=20$ and $\varphi (7)=6$, the corresponding subgroups $H_i$ of $G(K/\Bbb Q)$ have index $6$ and $20$ respectively.  That means their orders are $20$ and $6$.

Under the correspondence,  the intersection $E_1\cap E_2$ is the field corresponding to the join $\langle H_1,H_2\rangle $ of the subgroups.

We need that $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$.  One way to see that is to check that $E_1E_2=K$.

So that join has order $120$.  Thus $\langle H_1,H_2\rangle =G(K/\Bbb Q)$.

The whole Galois group corresponds to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Ah thanks for your answer. But how did you conclude the $[E1 \cap E2 :Q] =1$?

Comment: Under the correspondence.   Because $H_1×H_2=G(K/\Bbb Q)$.

Comment: Ok. Btw Do we have to say $H1H2$  Not $H1 \times H2$?

Comment: It's the compositum $\langle H_1,H_2\rangle $.  So we do need $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$.

Answer (score 4):

I'll finish @Jyrki_Lahtonen's comment. As $[E_1:\mathbb Q]=20$, by Sylow's theorem, the Galois group $\text{Gal}(E_1/\mathbb Q)$ has a unique (normal) subgroup of order $5$, which fixes a unique subfield of order $4$. We happen to know that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$ is an intermediate extension of degree $4$, hence must be the unique one. Any intermediate extension $F$ of degree $2$ must be fixed by a subgroup of order $10$ which must contain the unique Sylow $5$-subgroup of $\text{Gal}(E_1/\mathbb Q)$, and hence must be a subfield of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)$.

As $\text{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_5)/\mathbb Q)\simeq (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^{\times}$ which is cyclic, it has a unique subgroup of any fixed order. In particular, it can only have one subfield of degree $2$ which is fixed by the subgroup $\{\pm1\}\subset(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^{\times}$, hence the element $x=\zeta_5+\zeta_5^{-1}$ is in the subfield, and $x^2=\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3+2=(-1-x)+2$, $x^2+x-1=0$, $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Hence $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ is the unique subfield of degree $2$ in $E_1$.

Similarly, we can find that $x:=\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4$ satisfies $x^2=x+2(-1-x)$, $x^2+x+2=0$, $x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-7}}{2}$, and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-7})$ is the unique subfield of degree $2$ in $E_2$. However, while $\sqrt 5$ is real, $\sqrt{-7}$ is imaginary, hence $E_1\cap E_2=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Well done! Your handling of the degree 20 field was actually a bit slicker than what I had in mind :-)

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot from your posts.